# MongoDB node.js: index created ignoring TTL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab, ttl

I'm trying to create an index with TTL using the MongoDB driver for Node.js and a Mongo server hosted at mLab.

```
Node version 9.3.0.
Driver version 3.0.0.rc0
mongod version: 3.4.10 (MMAPv1)
```

Code in node.js:

```
var processCollection;

async function init (options) {
  processCollection = await options.db.collection('processes');

  await processCollection.dropIndexes();
  await processCollection.createIndex(
    { 'modified': 1 },
    { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 }
  );
}
```

Results in DB:

```
db['system.indexes'].find()
{
  "v": 2,
  "key": {
    "modified": 1
  },
  "name": "modified_1",
  "ns": "e-consular.processes"
}
```

The option `expireAfterSeconds` is missing in the resulting index. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collection.createIndex` is broken in versions 3.0.0rc0 and 3.0.0 of the Node mongodb driver. It will ignore the options object argument.

This was fixed in version 3.0.1 of the driver. (You can see the fix [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/commit/5461f46f85e58a30023005c37cb4f3aeab11ac8b)).

Update your driver to the latest version (e.g. `npm i mongodb@3.0.4`) and it should work as expected.

Comment: For those who are stuck with broken versions of the driver, replacing `createIndex` with `ensureIndex` is a valid workaround.